# Facebook smart friendlist via API

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

Trying to retrieve friends on **smart** (auto-generated) friendlists via the API, but it is returning no data.

Via graph explorer: `/<friendlist id>?fields=members`

If this is a custom list (not auto-generated) this returns:

```
{
  "id": "<friendlist id>", 
  "members": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "<friend id>", 
        "name": "<name>"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, with auto-generated lists I seem to get just the id back and no members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug for *smart lists*:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/471978009483097/